# Why Does AWS Lambda function finishes before callback function is executed?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, ibm-watson

I am working on a project to get the transcript out of an audio file. Audio files are of the format flac. I am using AWS Lambda and have written the code in node. Also, I am using IBM Speech to text service and using the basic example code given by them which can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?cm_mc_uid=11733379619915166475705&cm_mc_sid_50200000=99676171520219418861#recognize_audio_websockets). The problem is that my lambda function finishes before running these functions.

I am downloading a file from s3 and storing it locally(which is working fine). After that, I am trying to pass the same file to IBM Speech to Text SDK which should return the transcripts of the audio file to the local storage

Here is the code:

```
const downloadFile = function (url1, dest, cb) {
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    https.get(url1, function (res) {
        //res.setEncoding('binary');
        res.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function () {
            const stats = fs.statSync(dest);
            const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
        //Convert the file size to megabytes (optional)
            const fileSizeInMegabytes = fileSizeInBytes / 1000000.0;
            console.log(fileSizeInMegabytes);
            file.close();
            RunIBMWatson(dest);
            callback(null,"Nice");
        });
    });
};
function RunIBMWatson(dest){
    console.log(dest);
    console.log("I am here");

    const recognizeStream = speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream(params);
    fs.createReadStream(dest).pipe(recognizeStream);
    recognizeStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/transcription.txt'));
    recognizeStream.setEncoding('utf8');
    recognizeStream.on('results', function(event) { onEvent('Results:', event); });
    recognizeStream.on('data', function(event) { onEvent('Data:', event); });
    recognizeStream.on('error', function(event) { onEvent('Error:', event); });
    recognizeStream.on('close', function(event) { onEvent('Close:', event); });
    recognizeStream.on('speaker_labels', function(event) { onEvent('Speaker_Labels:', event); });

    function onEvent(name, event) {
      console.log("I am in onEvent");
      if (name === 'data'){
        console.log(event);
      }
```

and Here is the function logs that I get from AWS Lambda:

```
2018-03-05 03:31:53.585 54.093469
2018-03-05 03:31:53.588 /tmp/sample.flac
2018-03-05 03:31:53.588 I am here
```

I am a starter in both AWS Lambda and Node. So if anyone can point out the mistake I am making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea `RunIBMWatson` is an asynchronous function because of the file IO, so because you're not waiting for the result from that function to return - the callback is executed thus ending the execution of your lambda.

Wrap the logic of `RunIBMWatson` in a Promise and once all the data is obtained and written to that transcript file - resolve the function.  [MDN: Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
const downloadFile = function (url1, dest, cb) {

  ...
  console.log(fileSizeInMegabytes);
  file.close();
  return RunIBMWatson(dest)
  .then(() => { // return data from promise resolve can be back and accessible as params
    callback(null,"Nice");
  }
}

function RunIBMWatson(dest){

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const rStream = speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream(params);
    fs.createReadStream(dest).pipe(rStream);

    rStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/transcription.txt'));
    rStream.setEncoding('utf8');
    rStream.on('results', function(event) { onEvent('Results:', event); });
    rStream.on('data', function(event) { onEvent('Data:', event); });
    rStream.on('error', function(event) { onEvent('Error:', event); });
    rStream.on('close', function(event) { onEvent('Close:', event); });
    rStream.on('speaker_labels', function(event) { onEvent('Speaker_Labels:', event); });

    function onEvent(name, event) {
      console.log("I am in onEvent");
      if (name === 'data'){ // the data 
        resolve(); // you can return data too here
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the javascript event loop is empty so Lambda thinks it's done. You can download an npm module `async/await` which will help with that. [info here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asyncawait)

asyncawait is not included by default but that does not mean you cannot add it yourself. Simply add the package locally (npm install asyncawait), and include the node_modules folder in your ZIP before uploading your Lambda function.

If you want to handle dev dependencies separately (e.g.: test, aws-sdk to execute your function locally, etc), you can add them under devDependencies in your package.json.

Comment: thanks. that helped. Will start working with async/await